# c++ trying to understand clockwise rules for deciphering complicated syntax

Tags: c++

I have the following code:

```
int ia[3][4] = {    //
{0, 1, 2, 3},   //
{4, 5, 6, 7},   //
{8, 9, 10, 11}  //
};

int (*p4)[4] = ia;
cout << "(*(p4 + 0))[3] = " << (*(p4 + 0))[3] << endl;
cout << "*(p4 + 0)[3] = " << *(p4 + 0)[3] << endl;
```

gets the following output:

```
(*(p4 + 0))[3] = 3
*(p4 + 0)[3] = 1
```

I don't understand the last one how it arrives at 1.
Any help would be great.
Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't really arrive at 1. It just overindexes, and returns whatever it finds in memory: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b05820bece59dbc6

Answer (score 5):

> I don't understand the last one how it arrives at 1.

Undefined behavior got you there.

Due to operator precedence (the array indexing operator binds tighter than the pointer dereference operator),

`*(p4 + 0)[3]` is the same as:
`*((p4 + 0)[3])`, which is the same as:
`*(p4[3])`, which is the same as:
`p4[3][0]`.

For your array. the valid indices for the first dimension are: `0`, `1`, and `2`. Accessing the array using the index value of `3` accesses memory beyond valid range, leading to undefined behavior.

Comment: Thx! So the clockwise rule only refers to during declaration time or  in a function declaration?

Comment: @yapkm01, I haven't fully understood the clockwise rule.

Comment: @yapkm01, I have tried to make sense of it in the past, but it hasn't worked for me.

Comment: @yapkm01 the "clockwise rule" is not a *rule*. It's a helpful guidance that is *sometimes* right - it is not valid in all cases. So more of a "rule of thumb".

Comment: it seems from R.Sahu answer ..  *(p4[3]), which is the same as:
p4[3][0] .. it also means p4[3] = p4 + 3. did i get this right?

Comment: @yapkm01: Not quite. `p4[3] == *(p4 + 3)`

Comment: then R.Sahu answer would be *(p4[3]) = *(*(p4 + 3))?

Comment: @yapkm01, `*(*(p4+3))` is the same as `p4[3][0]`.

Comment: why is p4 + 3 which gives address of index 0 same as *(p4 + 3)?

Comment: @yapkm01, that is not what what we are saying. We are saying `p4[3]` is the same as `*(p4+3)`.

Comment: i understand but  .. i noticed something else that when i cout *(p4 + 1) gives same address (not value) as p4 + 1 .. i would expect the * in *(p4 + 1) to dereference to give me the value of 4

Comment: @yapkm01, an extended discussion on the subject is not encouraged here. If you have further questions, it will be better to put together another post that explains where you are having trouble understanding, with appropriate code that makes sense in that context.

Answer (score 1):

Postfix expressions have higher priority than unary expressions.

So this expression

```
*(p4 + 0)[3]
```

is equivalent to the expression

```
*( (p4 + 0)[3] )
```

As it is seen it is not the same as

```
( *(p4 + 0) )[3]
```

This expression `*( (p4 + 0)[3] )` can be written just like `*p4[3]` that is equivalent to `*ia[3]` and due to the priority is considered like

```
*( ia[3] )
```

or like

```
ia[3][0]
```

The valid range for indices of the first dimension for the array `ia` is `[0, 2]` because the array is declared like

```
int ia[3][4] = { /*...*/ };
      ^^^
```

Thus expression `ia[3]` tries to access memory beyond the array. As result the code snippet has undefined behavior.

Shortly speaking you should understand that these expressions

```
(*(p4 + 0))[3]
 *(p4 + 0)[3]
```

that in turn are equivalent to the following pair of expressions

```
ia[0][3]
io[3][0]
```

are not equivalent due to the priorities of the operations.

Comment: why *(p4 + 1) == p4 + 1? i noticed *(p4+1) gives me the address instead of value. Shouldn't  *(p4+1) gives value 4 since there's a * which is a deference operator?

Comment: @yapkm01 *(p4 + 1 ) is not equivalent to p4 + 1. In the last case the result of the expression is a pointer of the type int ( * )[4] and this pointer points to the second "row" of the array ia. The first expression due to applying the dereferencing yields this "row" itself that is an object of the type int[4].

Comment: @yapkm01 On the other hand the values stored in the pointer and the address of the row (and moreover of the first element of the row) are the same because it is the address of the same extent memory interpreted differently.

Comment: Gotcha! Thx a zillion!

Comment: @yapkm01 Consider a simple example. int a[10]; int ( *p )[10] = &a; int *q = &a[0]; The two pointers have the same value. It is the address where the extent allocated to the array starts. However the pointers have different types.